# How to deploy a Java EE dynamic web project to the net?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-hosting

I just finished my site using Java EE and bought a server and a domain name.

How can I heberge my site on the web?

Answer (score 1):

It is the same procedure like providing the Java EE Application on your local machine:

1. Install a JDK on your server
2. Install and configure the Application Server of your choice. 
    e.g.: [WildFly](http://wildfly.org/), [GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/), ...
3. Deploy your application
4. Maybe you also have to do some additional configuration on your Host Server, e.g. Port forwarding, creating a service to automatically start your Application Server, ...

As you can see a common web hoster would not be sufficient for your needs, so either you have to buy a dedicated server (or V-Server, ...) or you have to go to a special hoster for Java EE Application. There are some, but afaik they are quite expensive and you do not have that much control over your machine.